# Google Sitemap and .NET 1.1

Tags: .net, sitemap, .net-1.1

What is the best way for create a sitemap for google using .net 1.1 and use this sitemap in a treeview into a webpage .aspx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the .net sitemap control was introduced in framework 2.0, you may not have any option other than creating the file manually.

I would advise you to upgrade to framework 2.0.